How can I resolve npm compatibility issues with Node.js v14.21.3 and lockfileVersion in Ubuntu?
I'm currently working on a project in Ubuntu that requires Node.js version 14.21.3. However, when I try to run npm install in my project directory, I get the following warning message:
`npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
After researching, I found that updating npm to the latest version might help. I went ahead and upgraded npm, but now I get this error:
ERROR: npm v10.9.0 is known not to run on Node.js v14.21.3. This version of npm supports the following node versions: ^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/. 
So, I’m in a tricky situation:

If I stick with Node v14, I get compatibility issues with npm.
If I switch to Node v18, my project doesn’t work as it was originally built for Node v14.

Here I try to uninstall and then downgrade the npm but didn't work. So what do I do now ?
I tried to uninstall the latest npm so that I get the required npm version that supports node 14. But failed.
